# Access docker ports from a container inside another container at localhost

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have a setup where I build 2 dockers with docker-compose.

1 container is a web application. I can access it with port `8080`. Another container is ElasticSearch; it's accessible with port `9200`.

This is the content of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  serverapplication:
    build: "serverapplication"
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -x
      - init.sh
    command: ["jdbcUrl=${jdbcUrl} dbUser=${dbUser} dbUserPassword=${dbUserPassword}"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8787:8787"
  elasticsearch:
    build: "elasticsearch"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
```

When I browse to http://localhost:8080/serverapplication I can see my server application.
When I browse to http://localhost:9200/ I can see the default page of ElasticSearch.

But when I try to access ElasticSearch from inside the serverapplication, I get a "connection refused". It seems that the `9200` port is unreachable at localhost for the server application.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never safe to use localhost, since localhost means something else for your host system, for elasticsearch and for your server application. You're only able to access the containers from your host's localhost because you're mapping container ports onto your host's ports.

1. put them in the same network
2. give the containers a name
3. access elasticsearch through its containername, which Docker automatically resolves to the current IP of your elasticsearch container.

**Code:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  serverapplication:
    container_name: serverapplication
    build: "serverapplication"
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -x
      - init.sh
    command: ["jdbcUrl=${jdbcUrl} dbUser=${dbUser} dbUserPassword=${dbUserPassword}"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8787:8787"
    networks:
      - my-network

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build: "elasticsearch"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What do you mean with remark 3 that I need to configure the elasticsearch network host with the conaimer name "elasticsearch" ?

Comment: Neither `container_name:` nor any of the manual `networks:` configuration are necessary, and in the name of simplicity I’d suggest deleting these.

Comment: I don't agree, when you're still learning it's more important to be explicit. Even when you're not, there's still an argument to be made for it. At least it's easier for him to understand now why elasticsearch:9200 works. I know that a default bridge network is created, which is why it isn't really necessary to put it there.

Comment: In what sense to you mean "It's never _safe_ to use localhost"? I have been [searching to understand](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/274046/safe-or-not-elasticsearch-on-localhost-through-docker) why, or under what condition, hosting ES without security and ssl on a computer connected to the Internet is insecure. I figured "ports: 127.0.0.1:xxxx:xxxx" would be ok, because localhost is only accessible from my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Your server application must use the host name `elasticsearch` to access elasticsearch service i.e., `http://elasticsearch:9200`

Your serverapplication and elasticsearch are running in different containers. The `localhost` of `serverapplication` is different from `localhost` of `elasticsearch`.

`docker-compose` sets up a network between the containers such that they can be accessed with their service names. So from your `serverapplication`, you must use the name 'elasticsearch' to connect to it.